# Getting value inside Javascript toString

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have a very simple question.

In Javascript,

**"hello" + function(){}**

will print 
**"hellofunction(){}"**

because Function.prototype will call its own `toString` method and it will return "function(){}"

Now, I want to override toString method as:

```
Function.prototype.toString = function(){
return "my" + SOME_PROPERTY + "output"
}
```

Inside this custom method, I want to get `function(){}`
I want to know how to get this current value inside toString method since I can't execute `toString` again as it will go in recursion.

I want final output as:

```
"myfunction(){}output"
```

Answer (score 6):

By saving a reference to the *original* `Function.prototype.toString` function, you can `.call` it later, inside your custom `toString`, giving you the output you want and avoiding recursion:

```js
const origToString = Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString = function(){
  return "my" + origToString.call(this) + "output"
}
console.log("" + function(){});
```

Comment: That's cool!
Still thinking why I didn't try to store reference and run.
Thanks mate!!